# JavaFX: hide fixed pane with slider in SplitPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, splitpane

I have a [GridPane in a SplitPane](https://s1.postimg.org/24uy3jb53f/image.png).

I don't want to resize GridPane [when I slide](https://s1.postimg.org/407iw5pi57/image.png),

but I want to be able to [hide it](https://s1.postimg.org/6gtrb2wlrf/image.png).

If GridPane has fixed size, slider doesn't move.
Also, setting Resizable With Parent false didn't help.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I am going to guess that you should set the `GridPane`'s `minWidth` to the current side of the `GridePane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put you your gridpane inside a scrollPane then when it resizes it should only affect the scroll pane

Comment: ScrollPane partially solved the problem. It didn't hide completely because of the scroll bar. So, I tried several other panes. Using FlowPane and setting minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" worked.